# Number from oracle to String in java causing issue

Tags: java, oracle

In a table with number datatype I have stored 0.4

```
    String colLabel = rsMetadata.getColumnLabel(i);                         
    recordMap.put(colLabel.toLowerCase(), rs.getString(colLabel));
```

I use rs.getString to fetch the data.

But in java what I get is 4.00000000000000022204460492503130808473E-01

How can I go about this. This is a generic code where everytime rs.getString is used

Comment: One possible way: [more info here](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/recipes/ResultSet-ColumnType.shtml), basically you determinate data type and then use getString or getBigDecimal or the related method.

Comment: column is number and it is just select column_name

Comment: @TomJava - Any update? Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: Thank you Aravind. I followed a similar approach

Comment: @TomJava - You are most welcome. Wish you success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is

```
String colLabel = rsMetadata.getColumnLabel(i);                         
recordMap.put(colLabel.toLowerCase(), String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(rs.getString(colLabel))));
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("4.00000000000000022204460492503130808473E-01")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

The getter method of the appropriate type retrieves the value in each column. So you have to use resultSet's rs.getFloat() and that is what recommended. Getting all values with getString can be very useful, but it also has its limitations. In your case it is used to retrieve a numeric type, getString converts the numeric value to a Java String object and cannot be guaranteed that it will be the string representation of the value in the column.